# Nonrectangular Tensor Encountered error with rectangular matrices

Tags: matrix, dot

I have two matrices which are rectangular.  This code works with other applications I have but not this one.

```
BT = Transpose[B];
Dimensions[BT]         (* Out: {6, 3} *)
Dimensions[Dstress]    (* Out: {3, 3} *)
```

Then, when I try `BT.Dstress`, I obtain the following error:

> Nonrectangular tensor encountered

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
B={{{-(1/4)}, 0, {3/8}, 0, {-(1/8)}, 0},
   {0, {-(1/4)}, 0, {-(1/8)}, 0, {3/8}},
 {{-(1/4)}, {-(1/4)}, {-(1/8)}, {3/8}, {3/8}, {-(1/8)}}}

Dstress = EI/(1 - v^2) ({{1, v, 0},
                         {v, 1, 0},
                         {0, 0, (1 - v)/2}})
```

These are my matrices
v=.33

Comment: Try `ArrayQ /@ {BT, Dstress}`. If either one of the results is not `True`, then the internal structure of your "matrices" may not be what you expect. You could then check the one that returns False with `Dimensions /@ <questionableMatrix>`. To say more, you will have to share the definitions of `B` and `Dstress`.

Comment: I added the definitions

Comment: for BT I am getting  
{{3}, {3}, {3}, {3}, {3}, {3}},  So I am assuming it should work fine

Comment: You have many extra irregular layers of braces. Look at `Dimensions /@ B` which returns `{{6}, {6}, {6, 1}}`. That is not a rectangular array. Was this generated from e.g. `Solve` via replacement rules?

Answer (score 1):

You have many extra irregular layers of braces. Look at `Dimensions /@ B` which returns `{{6}, {6}, {6, 1}}`: that is not a rectangular array.

Reshape your array into a rectangular one of the appropriate dimensions:

```
Brect = ArrayReshape[B, {3, 6}]

(* Out: {{-(1/4), 0, 3/8, 0, -(1/8), 0}, {0, -(1/4), 0, -(1/8), 0, 3/8},
         {-(1/4), -(1/4), -(1/8), 3/8, 3/8, -(1/8)}} *)
```

Then carry out the dot product:

```
Dstress = EI/(1 - v^2) ({{1, v, 0}, {v, 1, 0}, {0, 0, (1 - v)/2}})
Transpose[Brect].Dstress
```